# Custom Task-Like class with an additional state

Tags: c#, async-await

My question is based around this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/extending-the-async-methods-in-c/)

I am wandering if it is possible to extend this task like scenario to return an additional status or value other than the result value. To set a base line just a simple snippet of code below that shows how you can check the completed status of the task.

```cs
async Task Method()
{
    var task = // some method that returns a Task<int>
    Console.WriteLine(task.IsCompleted); // prints false
    await task;
    Console.WriteLine(task.IsCompleted); // prints true
}
```

So what I am curious about is, is it possible to when creating a custom task like class to extend it to return an additional status property that you set yourself. For my example lets say I want a custom task for responses from a method that performs an asynchronous http operations.
Lets assume I have created a task like object called `Response<T>` and set up the builder and awaiter objects as per the article linked above.

Is it possible to extend the task like response object to return the `HttpStatusCode` as a status as well IsCompleted, so that you can access it in method similar to below.

```cs
async Task Method()
{
    var response = // some method that returns a Response<Dto>
    Console.WriteLine(response.HttpStatusCode); // prints null
    Console.WriteLine(task.IsCompleted); // prints false
    var dto = await response;
    Console.WriteLine(task.HttpStatusCode); // prints say 'OK'
    Console.WriteLine(task.IsCompleted); // prints true
}
```

Comment: @MickyD It is a typo, meant to be true.

Comment: `Task` and `Task<T>` can be extended or you can create a class that has an implicit conversion to the aforementioned classes. However, you can't define an `async` method that statically returns your type

Comment: @Heinrich: Real-world code almost never uses custom awaitables *or* custom tasklikes. If you want a status/result that is accessible (with a default value) before the task completes, I recommend using something like [`NotifyTask<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/56956a4e2e7eaecfaa9fdc423775057b8a909c91/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs#L174).

Comment: @StephenCleary I am aware of that fact, this question was primarily out of curiosity.